# Evaluating integral $\int\frac{2(\cos x + \sin x)}{\sin 2x} dx$

Tags: calculus, integration

Evaluate

$$\int\frac{2(\cos x + \sin x)}{\sin 2x} dx$$

I have tried a few times and came up with an answer

$$-\ln | \csc x + \cot x| +\frac 12\ln |\tan x + \sec x| + C$$

which is incorrect. I just need someone to explain what is wrong with my answer.

Comment: in the body, the first $2$ is outside the parentheses, unlike in the title

Comment: Is "my answer" the expression that is labelled "Entered" in the image?  If so, I suspect the square brackets are not permitted as grouping punctuation.  You don't say where you are using this answer, so there is no way to test the suspicion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use $\sin2x =2\sin x\cos x$,

$$\int\frac{2(\cos x + \sin x)}{\sin 2x} dx
=\int\frac1{\sin x} dx+ \int \sec x dx $$
$$=\ln \tan \frac x2 + \ln (\tan x + \sec x) + C$$

where the two integrals are obtained as follows

$$\int\frac{dx}{\sin x}=\int\frac{dx}{2\sin \frac x2\cos\frac x2}
=\int\frac{\sec^2\frac x2dx}{2\tan\frac x2}=\ln \tan \frac x2 $$

$$\int \sec x dx = \int \frac{\sec x\tan x + \sec^2 x}{\tan x + \sec x}dx
=\int \frac{d(\tan x+ \sec x)}{\tan x + \sec x}=  \ln (\tan x + \sec x)$$